# Wordpress shortcode rendering incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to echo something like this using a wordpress shortcode:

```
<a href="some/link.html><div class="rhinoButton">Submit</div></a>
```

I am using this code to make the shortcode:

```
function rhino_button_shortcode( $atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'label' => 'Submit',
            'url' => '',
        ), $atts, 'rhinoButton' );

    return '<a href="'.$atts['url'].'"><div class="rhinoButton">'.$atts['label'].'</div></a>';
}

add_shortcode('rhinoButton', 'rhino_button_shortcode');
```

But instead it outputs:

```
<div class="rhinoButton"><a href="some/link.html>Submit</a></div>
```

It's nesting the `<a>` inside the `</div>` (which is backwards).

I've heard this can happen if you're echoing instead of returning, but I'm not. I've also tried output buffering with `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean` with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try with `span`?

Comment: Why did that work??

Comment: Are you using this shortcode in wordpress admin editor?

Comment: Ah yes, so it probably has to do with tinyMCE and/or WP content filters?

Comment: yes. issue with inyMCE and/or WP content filters

Comment: Your function is working as per your output.

Comment: WP content filters usually run at the default priority 10, shortcodes are handled by do_shortcode() which runs at priority 11 so I don't see how WP content filters can cause this problem unless some theme or plugin has installed some 'the_content' filter with priority greater than 11.

Comment: @Eckstein I find this problem very interesting and I am willing to spend a lot of time and effort to understand it. However, I will need you to run experiments so you will also need to spend time and effort. Let me know if you are willing. I really think your code should work. Can you use a PHP debugger? Or at least know how to use error_log() ?

Comment: I tested the filters: wptexturize, convert_smilies, wpautop, shortcode_unautop, prepend_attachment and wp_make_content_images_responsive individually and they don't move the div outside the a. Anyway, except for convert_smilies they should not be relevant as they run at priority 10 (convert_smilies runs at 20). There really is something strange going on here. May I ask what theme and plugins you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I added your code to my theme's function.php and tested with this shortcode

```
[rhinoButton url="https://www.google.com"]
```

This generated the following:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com"><div class="rhinoButton">Submit</div></a>
```

I captured this from the page source in the browser.

So, your code works as expected on my installation WordPress 4.9.5 running the Twenty Sixteen theme. I think some theme or plugin you have installed is adding a 'the_content' filter with priority > 11.

If you are willing to run some experiments for me I can help you track this down.

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help! Since the <span> solution worked, I need to move forward with the project to get it launched, but I may return here in the future to solve the mystery! I am actually developing a custom theme and have several plugins installed that hook into the display of the content (for translations and a couple other things) so there could be lots of reasons. Thanks again though!